# Считывание символов из файла с++

Tags: c++, c++11

Нужно считать N-ное кол-во символов из файла. Вопрос стоит в чем: Как узнать длинну строки в файле (когда слова разделены пробелом, то считывается только 1 слово, которое идет до пробела и всё)
Испрльзовал fstream файловые потоки

Comment: *Нужно считать N-ное кол-во символов из файла* - Можно N раз сделать `getc(file)`, но лучше `fread`

Comment: `..gcount()` - количество последних прочитанных символов, `.tellg()` - текущая позиция. Оно?

Comment: а что такое символ? в зависимости от кодировки символ может быть от 1 до 4 байт, вам известна кодировка файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример посимвольного чтения из файла:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char sim;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    int count = 19;
    int i = 0;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile.get(sim) && i<count)
        {
            cout << sim;
            i++;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод

```
This is a line.
Thi
```

Если нужно найти количество символов в файле:

```
int main () {
streampos begin, end;
ifstream myfile("example.txt");
begin = myfile.tellg();
myfile.seekg(0, ios::end);
end = myfile.tellg();
myfile.close();
cout << "Length: " << (end - begin) << " symbols.\n";
}
```

Comment: Тут заранее задана длинна строки. Там может быть и 300 символов, так вот в этом вопрос, как узнать длинну строки в файле? На подобии str.lenght()

Comment: Где тут? В примере считывается из файла 19 символов.